# geometry question from kangaroo math contest

Tags: geometry, word-problem

[drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAUjD.jpg)

> A rectangle has sides of length 6cm and 11cm. One long side is
> selected. The bisectors of the angles at either end of that side are
> drawn. These bisectors divide the other long side into 3 parts. What
> are the lengths of these parts? The options are
>
> a) 1, 9, 1;
>
> b) 2, 7, 2;
>
> c) 3, 5, 3;
>
> d) 4, 3, 4;
>
> e) 5, 1, 5.

I drew a rectangle and a bisector coming out of each end at a 45 degree angle which divided the other long side into 3 parts but I don't know if I drew the bisectors right because I couldn't find a way that will for sure give the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The bisectors make isosceles triangles. You should find they cross before they reach the other side of the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by 'find they cross before they reach the other side of the rectangle'

Comment: Draw a figure!!  (How can you do geometry without figures???)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Since Descartes we can do that, using algebra instead.

Comment: Of course you *can* avoid drawings, but doing so prevents you from seeing obvious (and potentially embarrassing) facts about a situation—particularly when it is a trivial matter, like where lines must intersect.

Answer (score 1):

$The \;bisectors\; make\; right\; angle\; isosceles\;triangles,\; vertex\; is\; inside\; rectangle, \;since\; 6>11/2,\; y \;is\; the\; height\; of\; the\; smaller\; one,\;  x\; is\; a \;foot\; on \;the \;side\; to\; be\; solved.  $

$y= \frac {x} {2} $

$Appropriate\; right\; angle \;triangles\; are\; similar,\; thus\;$

$\frac {x} {11}=\frac {y} {6-y}$

$\frac {x} {11}=\frac {\frac {x} {2}} {6-\frac {x} {2}}$

$x=1,\; other\; segments\; are\; 5\; each$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is e) $5, 1, 5$

You can solve it with the following algebra.

Let $a$ be the first part of the segment.
Let $b$ be the second part of the segment.
Let $c$ be the third part of the segment.

$$a+b+c = 11,
a+b = 6,
b+c = 6$$

Therefore:
$$a = 5, b = 1, c = 5$$